# text decoration not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a website with a contacts page.

on this page I have my email address which is linked in a mailto anchor. The email displays in the usual unvisited blue with an underline.

**trying to remove this is where the problem starts**

My code for this link is:

```
<li>
<div class="icon email">Email:</div>
<div class="email_info" style="text-decoration:none"><a href="mailto:kevin@kh.co.uk">kevin@kh.co.uk</a></div>

</li>
```

I have tried adding `text-decoration:none` to the `ul` and `li` in my CSS code but none of them seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to add it to the `a` tag.

Comment: And better to put it in a CSS stylesheet file than inline in your HTML

Comment: can you be a little more clear?

Comment: tried that before and it did not work. trying it again now works. strange. thank you. tho.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `text-decoration: none;` to the `a` element not the container `div`.

Inline styles (defining CSS via the `style` attribute on individual elements) is also generally bad practice - you should put it in an external stylesheet, or at least in your `head` like so:

```
<style>
    .email_info a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following...

```
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS

```
.email_info a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: well I know its just me but I hate the blue underline look on all of my web pages that I create. so I used this `a:link {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}
a:active {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}` and it does the same as yours but across the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

if that doesn't work:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Link</a>
```

and just put it in the link itself